# Is $\frac{x}{1+e^x} $ uniformly continuous or not (on $\mathbb{R}$)?

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+e^x} $ and I need to show if it is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ or not.

I think it does but the rules I know doesn't work in this case so I tried to use the definition. 
for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\lambda>0$ so when $ |x-y|<\lambda $ then $ |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ but I didn't find the connection between $ |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ and $ |x-y|<\lambda $

Comment: I don't know if you find this helpful, but by considering what happens near 0, and then as x tends to plus/minus infinity, you can sketch the graph and see the derivative is bounded.... (Tryss was more precise!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see that the derivative is bounded :

$$f'(x) = \frac{1+e^x - xe^x}{(1+e^x)^2} $$

It's continuous over $\mathbb{R}$ and as $\lim_{x\to + \infty} f'(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to - \infty} f'(x) = 1$, it is bounded : $|f'(x)| < M$ with $M>0$.

So by the mean value theorem,

$$f(x) - f(y) = (x-y)f'(c)$$

So this gives you

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le M|x-y|$$

It then suffice to take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M}$

Comment: are you sure it's 0 in $-\infty$? because $1+e^x$ goes to 1 and $e^x(1-x)$ goes to $0*-\infty$ so i used l'hopital rule on $\frac{1-x}{\frac{1}{e^x}}$ and it's 0 so $1+e^x(1-x)$ is 1 and the limit is 1. Did I had an error in my calculations?

Comment: @user259105 : you're right. I corrected this error,  it's indeed 1 at $-\infty$. It doesn't change the core of the argument

Comment: yeah it's still okay, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x)$ is small for $x\gg 0$ and $f(x)-x=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}\cdot x$ is small for $x\ll 0$.